# Error in NS2 debugging using Eclipse: "Cant find a source file at... "

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ubuntu, gdb, ns2

I am trying to debug NS-2.34 using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 under Ubuntu 13.10, and I had successfully configured NS2 and Eclipse for debugging by following the instructions from here "https://erl1.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/using-ns-2-with-eclipse/." The problem is, when I start debugging, debugging will not continue due to the error

> Can't find a source file at "/build/buildd/eglibc-2/17/elf/dl-debug.c"
>
> Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location

I tried to locate the file in my system but I can't seem to figure that part out. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's one of the many reasons why a lot of people transfer from NS2 to NS3 when they find that the module they would like to use is available in NS3.

For your problem, the page you are referring to has been a long time ago and there might be conflicts caused by new version.

For me, as a ns2er, when I modified some code or add new files, I just do "make" command and see what I got in the terminal. It works in most of the time.

Cheers,

Zeyu